# Delete operation is failing to delete a document in mongo using groovy in Jmeter

Tags: mongodb, groovy, jmeter

IAm trying to delete a document i created through my script using deleteone as well as deletemany using following code:

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import org.bson.Document;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.*;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import java.util.Arrays;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import com.mongodb.MongoCredential;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import org.bson.Document;



try {

String mongoUser = vars.get("mongouser");
String userDB = vars.get("userdb");
char[] password = vars.get("password").toCharArray();
MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(mongoUser, userDB, password);
MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
.applyToClusterSettings {builder -> 
builder.hosts(Collections.singletonList(new ServerAddress(vars.get("mongohost"), vars.get("mongoPort") as int)))}
.credential(credential)
.build();
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(settings);


MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase(vars.get("databaseName"));
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection(vars.get("collectionName1"));
vars.putObject("collection1", collection);

    collection.deleteone(eq("EmployeeName", "Test Automation through Jmeter"));

    return "Document deleted";
}
catch (Exception e) {
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
    SampleResult.setResponseCode("500");
    SampleResult.setResponseMessage("Exception: " + e);}
```

getting this error:

```
Response message: Exception: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.deleteone() is applicable for argument types: (com.mongodb.client.model.Filters$
```

SimpleEncodingFilter) values: [Filter{fieldName='EmployeeName', value=Test Automation through Jmeter}]
    Possible solutions: deleteOne(org.bson.conversions.Bson), deleteOne(com.mongodb.client.ClientSession, org.bson.conversions.Bson), deleteOne(org.bson.conversions.Bson, com.mongodb.client.model.DeleteOptions), deleteOne(com.mongodb.client.ClientSession, org.bson.conversions.Bson, com.mongodb.client.model.DeleteOptions), deleteMany(org.bson.conversions.Bson), deleteMany(com.mongodb.client.ClientSession, org.bson.conversions.Bson)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the method is called `deleteOne`, not `deleteone`, so the correct way to call it should be:

```
collection.deleteOne(eq("EmployeeName", "Test Automation through Jmeter"));
```

See also the javadocs for the `MongoCollection`: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/?com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html